# how to do css styling

Tags: html, css

A very simple task in hand.. but my browser is laughing on my face with my futile attempts.

How do I style a div class just around the text

So I am using jinja on backend and my html looks like this

```
<div class="content">
<pre>  {{contents}}</pre>
</div>
```

and my css is

```
div.content {
    background-color: #add8e6;

}
```

But what is happening is.. if "content" is half the line.. this styling is running across the whole horizontal line..
I just want to gracefully wrap the color across the text rather than whole horizontal page.
When I try

```
display: inline;
```

all the background color vanishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block`

```
div.content {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    display:inline-block

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KNq8j/)**

**Difference between `inline` and `inline-block`**

**inline-block** - This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

**inline** - This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div.content * {
    background-color: #add8e6;
}
```

This will apply the style to all the elements within the div block.